# Eclipse stuck on refresh project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, synchronization

I am using eclipse for PHP development.

Unfortunately, since yesterday the files are described as "Resource x does not exist". I tried to refresh the project, but it doesn't help, since the windows that shows the refresh progress bar gets stuck.
I already tried the command-line option `-clean` with no success.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: *"I am using eclipse for PHP development."*  So why also the Java tag onto your question?  Nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting and reimporting the project.

Comment: Because this is not a solution. It's like saying "did you try to turn it off and on?". Deleting a whole project and reimporting might be a hack, an ugly workaround, but is not a proper solution to the problem.

Comment: Fair enough.  But, your question was about how to fix the problem, not what the problem is. Since it seems to me that your project metadata is corrupt, deleting and reimporting is a valid possible solution (just like turning it off and on).  The other idea that I have is to delete the entire .metadata folder (since it may be corrupt) and rebuilding your workspace, but that is even more of a pain.